# Deserializing this JSON in C# with Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#

How should I parse it with Newtonsoft.Json ?

```
[[[671,1]],[[2011,1],[1110,1]],[[2001,1],[673,1]],[[1223,1],[617,1],[685,1]],[[671,1],[1223,2],[685,1]]]
```

Comment: what did you try?

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have a `List<List<List<int>>>>` there:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string test = "[[[671, 1]],[[2011,1],[1110,1]],[[2001,1],[673,1]],[[1223,1],[617,1],[685,1]],[[671,1],[1223,2],[685,1]]]";

            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<List<int>>>>(test);

            for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; ++i)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Page: {i}");

                for (int j = 0; j < result[i].Count; ++j)
                    Console.WriteLine($"Row {j}: " + string.Join(", ", result[i][j]));
            }

        }
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
Page: 0
Row 0: 671, 1
Page: 1
Row 0: 2011, 1
Row 1: 1110, 1
Page: 2
Row 0: 2001, 1
Row 1: 673, 1
Page: 3
Row 0: 1223, 1
Row 1: 617, 1
Row 2: 685, 1
Page: 4
Row 0: 671, 1
Row 1: 1223, 2
Row 2: 685, 1
```

Note that you could also use `int[][][]`:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<int[][][]>(test);
```

If you do that, you'd have to use `.Length` instead of `.Count` of course.

Comment: Thanks so much! Didn't realize Newtonsoft library support such nested generic types!